# How to stop python script from hanging when used "subprocess" module to start applications

Tags: python, freeze

so I scripted an executable program with tkinter in Python, and it serves as an launcher for my apps. It has buttons to be pressed to execute command `subprocess.call`. But when I use it to start an app, the whole script hangs and my system Windows 10 sees it as not responding. Everything only goes back to normal after I close the process that the script started. I used `try` `except` but it did not do anything. My expectation is that the script starts the app and goes on to continue waiting for the next command from the user. How do I achieve that?

Comment: Use a non-blocking call. There are many example in the [docs of subprocess module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
import os
import threading

def noHangFunction():
    os.system("whoami") #os.system or subprocess is similar result

backgroundFunction = threading.Thread(target=noHangFunction, args=(), kwargs={})
backgroundFunction.start()
```

Comment: Did not really solve the issue of script not responding but thanks for the contribution!

Comment: @Wind_Explorer Yes, but this code allows the code to continue regardless of the system call's status. Isn't that what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

Ok problem solved I replaced my `subprocess.call` with `subprocess.Popen` and everything works now :D